# Threshold Encryption Scheme for Multiple Messages

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, threshold-cryptography

In a threshold encryption scheme, a dealer generates $(PK,SK1,…,SKn)$ and distributes the secret keys to users indexed by $1,…,n$, and if a combiner obtains $t+1$ partially-decrypted ciphertexts, it can retrieve a plaintext.

When only for one message $M$, we can first use public key $PK$ to encrypt $m$ and get $C$, then use $t$ private key fragments $Ski$, $i∈[0,…,t]$,  to partially decrypt the $C$, which named $SKi(C)$($i∈[0,…,t]$), and then perform some operations on the $t$ results to restore the original Message $M$. For this situation, $(t,n)$-threshold Paillier scheme is feasible.

But when we have multiple messages $Mi$, $i∈[0,…,t]$, we also use the $PK$ to encrypt them separately, which named $PK(Mi)=Ci$, $i∈[0,…,t]$, and we define that each message can only be partially decrypted using the corresponding private key fragment, like $SKi(Ci)$, $i∈[0,…,t]$. In this case, can we use these decrypted results to restore each original message $Mi$($i∈[0,…,t]$) or get the sum of all messages $∑M_i $ ?